# ¿Cómo matar el proceso del servidor de django con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ubuntu

Tengo un VPS con Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.5 y django 2.0.6. He creado un script llamado **start.py** para automatizar que: cuando el usuario se conecte mediante putty-SSH al servidor se inicie el servidor de pruebas de django (**python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000**) y después abra el navegador google-chrome en el equipo del usuario (mediante **Xming** instalado en su equipo). Cuando el usuario termina de usar el navegador y lo cierra, debo matar el proceso del servidor de django para que no se quede abierto para las próximas sesiones, o de lo contrario lanza un error que informa que el puerto está siendo usado por otro proceso.

Este sería el script:

```
import subprocess
django = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "LibrosWeb/manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000"])
chrome = subprocess.call(["google-chrome", "127.0.0.1:8000"])
django.kill()
print("FIN DEL PROCESO")
```

Todo funciona bien, excepto que cuando termino la sesión del chrome y compruebo los procesos abiertos, el proceso de django y el de postgres siguen ahi, como si kill() no funcionara.

```
lsof -i

python3 12021 gela    3u  IPv4 493782      0t0  TCP localhost:37758->localhost:postgresql (ESTABLISHED)
python3 12021 gela    4u  IPv4 493789      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
```

La única manera que he podido es hacerlo manualmente mediante **kill -9 PID** desde la línea de comandos, pero lo que quiero es hacer todo el proceso de forma automática.
También he probado esto:

```
pid = str(django.pid) 
print("FIN DEL PROCESO: ", pid) 
subprocess.call(["kill", "-9", pid]) 

>> FIN DEL PROCESO: 14964 
>> lsof -i 
>> python3 14981 gela 3u IPv4 507794 0t0 TCP localhost:38366->localhost:postgresql (ESTABLISHED) 
>> python3 14981 gela 4u IPv4 507801 0t0 TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
```

El PID no es el mismo. Parece que el servidor de django abre diferentes procesos y siguen abiertos despues del kill que solo mata el proceso principal, pero deja los otros dos, o tal vez no llega a matar ningún proceso. La verdad ahora lo entiendo menos que antes.

Comment: ¿Por qué no sacar el PID del proceso y ejecutas el comando **kill -9 PID** desde el script?

Comment: Puedes escribir en varias líneas, aunque te recomiento que edites tu pregunta y lo añadas ahí.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución usando **pkill**. Este sería el código final:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["python3", "LibrosWeb/manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000"])
subprocess.call(["google-chrome", "127.0.0.1:8000"])
subprocess.call(["pkill", "-f", "python3 LibrosWeb/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000"])
```

Aquí un enlace de un problema similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411394/appropriate-signal-to-kill-django-development-server